# Private messages in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, plugins

I use Symfony 2.8 There are website on it where users can register. I need to add the possibility of private messages between users. Is there a plugin that will do this?

Comment: Could have found this simply by googling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [FOSMessage](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessage), it is really easy to use and manage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try FOSMessage :)